# how to find last position given a time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

I found this formula (I dont know its name) and I'm trying to apply it in order to find the last position given a time and velocity.

$ s = s_0 + v_0 \cdot t + \frac{1}{2} \cdot a \cdot t² $

given

$ t = 3h $

$ v = 100km/h $

$ a= \frac{v}{t} $

results

$
s = 0 + 0 \cdot 3 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{100}{3} \cdot 3²\\
s = 150km
$

Although I was expecting the same result of $ \Delta_s = \Delta_v \cdot t $ that would be $300km$. That mean if I remove the $\frac{1}{2}$ part of the equation it will give me the expected result. Why is that? Is that formula wrong or what am I missing? Or what is that formula useful for then?

Comment: Study what SUVAT equations mean. You need to understand what acceleration is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made the following 2 mistakes :
1. $a = v/t$.NO !  $a = \frac{dv}{dt}$, in case there is no change in velocity $va = 0$.
2. $\Delta S = \Delta v t$. again, $\Delta S = vt + \frac{at^2}{2}$ and when $a=0$ $\Delta S = vt$.

Since you have only been given a velocity and no acceleration, the velocity must be constant and therefore $\Delta S = vt$.

Answer (score 0):

> That mean if I remove the
>   part $\frac{1}{2}$ of the equation it will give me the expected result. Why is that? Is that formula wrong or what am I missing?

Given that the distance traveled at constant acceleration is:

$$s=s_0+v_0t+\frac{1}{2}at^2$$

If it starts from rest, $t_0=0$ and $s_0=0$:

$$s=\frac{1}{2}at^2=\frac{v}{2t}t^2=\frac{\Delta vt}{2}$$

This is why the right answer is the wrong answer divided by two.